# jQuery Remove Closest Issues in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-chrome, cross-browser

Noob here sorry. I'm trying to remove an ancestor when my WP loop returns an empty message with a specific class. Firefox is displaying as intended, removing the desired DOM, but Chrome is removing the targeted element and no ancestors.

Basic HTML markup:

```
<div id="content" class="container site-content">
  <div id="primary" class="main-content">
    <div id="main-box-1" class="main-box border-top">
      <div class="main-box-inside">
        <p class="no-modules-msg">No posts match your criteria. Please choose different options.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-box-2" class="main-box border-top  ">
      <h3 class="main-box-title">More Stuff</h3>
      <div class="main-box-inside">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my script:

```
(function($) {
  $("document.body").ready(function() {
    $("p.no-modules-msg")
      .closest(".main-box")
      .remove(".main-box")
  })
})(jQuery);
```

It's working correctly in fiddle, but not on the live site...

https://jsfiddle.net/y90gtt6t/

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's not working on your site, is because the documentation is quite clear, only the `document` has a ready handler

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("p.no-modules-msg").closest(".main-box").remove()
});
```

Your use of `"document.body"` actually looks for an element like `<document class="body"></document>`, which it hopefully never finds.

Comment: I added that based on a thread here to no avail, and should've removed it. I've tried your exact code, and am getting the same results of FF removing the ancestor .main-box, while Chrome is removing the p.no-modules-msg instead.

Comment: @user3015094 - I changed it slightly, but it should remove the closest `.main-box` in all browser, here's a test -> https://jsfiddle.net/unckjbv7/

Comment: Thanks, but Chrome / Edge is still removing only the <p>

Comment: That's not really possible, unless the `<p>` has the class `.main-box`

Comment: It doesn't. Just .no-modules-msg is on the <p>

Comment: Then something else is happening, the above code would never remove the `<p>`, only the closest `.main-box`, in all browsers ?